# Unexpected behaviour of MomentOfInertia

Tags: computational-geometry

The problem I expected Mathematica to solve rather easily is that of the calculus of a moment of inertia of a "c" section defined by the following Polygon:

```
sezione = 
  Polygon[{{-0.06, 0.09}, {0.10, 0.09}, {0.10, 0.07}, {-0.04, 
     0.07}, {-0.04, -0.07}, {0.1, -0.07}, {0.1, -0.09}, {-0.06, \
-0.09}}];
MomentOfInertia[sezione]
MomentOfInertia[sezione, RegionCentroid[sezione]]
RegionCentroid[sezione]
MomentOfInertia[sezione, {-0.00130435, 0}]
```

I expected the outputs to be the same! Instead they aren't at all as the first element of the matrix changes unexpectedly. Why is this? If I specify the coordinates of the center of mass it doesn't give the same answer! Also, I believe the *last answer* is the correct answer.

**EDIT**

These are my outputs:

```
{{0.0000991333, -9.*10^-7}, {-9.*10^-7, 0.000074011}}
{{0.0000991333, -9.*10^-7}, {-9.*10^-7, 0.000074011}}
{-0.00130435, 0.}
{{0.0000457467, -9.*10^-7}, {-9.*10^-7, 0.000074011}}
```

If one would rationalize the input (as suggested), you would get the following answer:

```
N[MomentOfInertia[Rationalize[sezione]]]
```

You would have the correct answer:

```
{{0.0000457467, 0.}, {0., 0.000023291}}
```

I believe this could be a bug. As it is self-evident that users replying to my question have different answers with the exact same code. My version is Mathematica 10.4 Student Edition.

Comment: Try removing the repeated point.

Comment: It is the same! I didn't have it firstly. @J.M.

Comment: Really? It works if I remove either the first or the last point in my tests.

Comment: I've quit the Kernel and no, it doesn't work! @J.M.

Comment: What version and OS are you on? Another possibility: try applying `Rationalize[]` to your points.

Comment: Make sure you checked not the first two answers, instead confront the last with the first two.
Anyhow I'm working on a Ubuntu 14.04 with Mathematica 10.4 Student Edition. @J.M.

Comment: Wow! @J.M. It works only rationalizing. This is amazing. How is this? Could you please explain??

Comment: What differences are you finding extremely different?  Is it -1.69407*10^-21 vs. -8.47033*10^-22 ?  If so, given the precision of the input data, aren't both of those numbers essentially zero?

Comment: Oh, no. One result is double the other. These are my outputs: {{0.0000991333, -9.*10^-7}, {-9.*10^-7, 0.000074011}} (the first one, and it is wrong); this is the second: {{0.0000457467, -9.*10^-7}, {-9.*10^-7, 0.000074011}}. As you may see the first element is almost double! This is giving me some doubts over the reliability of other things I've done using this function! @JimBaldwin

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by @J.M. using `Rationalize` will help (by avoiding round-off error).

But you've also put in a rounded number (-0.00130435) in your last statement that also contributes to differences.  Here's a list of statements (and outputs) from Mathematica 10.4.1 (Windows 7):

```
sezione = 
  Polygon[{{-0.06, 0.09}, {0.10, 0.09}, {0.10, 0.07}, {-0.04, 0.07},
{-0.04, -0.07}, {0.1, -0.07}, {0.1, -0.09}, {-0.06, -0.09}}];

MomentOfInertia[sezione]
    (* {{0.00004574666666666663`,-1.6940658945086007`*^-21},
       {-1.6940658945086007`*^-21,0.000023291014492753617`}} *)
MomentOfInertia[sezione, RegionCentroid[sezione]]
    (* {{0.00004574666666666663`,-1.6940658945086007`*^-21},
       {-1.6940658945086007`*^-21,0.000023291014492753617`}} *)
RegionCentroid[sezione]
    (* {-0.0013043478260869653`,0.`} *)
MomentOfInertia[sezione, {-0.00130435, 0}]
    (* {{0.00004574666666666663`,-8.470329472543003`*^-22},
       {-8.470329472543003`*^-22,0.000023291014492753658`}} *)

rc = RegionCentroid[sezione]
MomentOfInertia[sezione, rc]
    (* {{0.00004574666666666663`,-1.6940658945086007`*^-21},
       {-1.6940658945086007`*^-21,0.000023291014492753617`}} *)


MomentOfInertia[Rationalize[sezione]]
    (* {{3431/75000000, 0}, {0, 40177/1725000000}} *)

N[MomentOfInertia[Rationalize[sezione]]]
    (* {{0.00004574666666666667`,0.`},{0.`,0.000023291014492753624`}} *)
```

Comment: Ok. I believe we are missing the point. If I run your code on my version of Mathematica I receive different answers as I've lastly written in the comments above. I suppose this is a error and it might have been corrected in your version.

Comment: It would help others if you would edit your question and put in your version of *Mathematica* and the results you obtained as those can be missed if they are only in the comments.  Also, doesn't obtaining 0.00074011 concern you if the correct answer is 0.000023291 ? (assuming the input precision is exact)

Comment: Ok. I'll edit my question.